# Help me understand this one line of jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables

```
var div = $(this), ul = $("ul", div), li = $("li", ul);
```

**Please explain, what does this code do?**

By steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It ends up with these equivalents:

```
var div = $(this);
var ul = $(this).find("ul");
var li = $(this).find("ul").find("li");
```

So it's getting the current `<div>`, any `<ul>` elements inside it, and any `<li>` elements inside those, and placing each collection in its own variable.

When you do `$(selector, content)` [you're actually doing](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L155) `$(context).find(selector)` under the covers, so the code in your question is just chaining one call to the next, effectively doing a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) inside each time.

Comment: +1 for a fun-to-read and accurate explanation. Is it just me, or is the stupid `$(selector, content)` way of selecting elements a pain in the ass to read? What is wrong with `find`?

Comment: @karim79 - nope not just you, it seems to be counter to the whole fluent/chain style of the library, totally backwards imo...not to mention less efficient.